# Padding within display: table-cell extends past container

Tags: css, padding

I am using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to allow columns in my layout to extend all the way to the bottom with `height: 100%`.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="menu">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: white;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.subcontainer{
    display: table-cell !important;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbELK/

The problem:
I want to add some `padding-top` to `.menu`. The problem is that this padding causes `.menu` to extend past its parent container, causing all sorts of problems:
[image]

I would like to use paddings and margins for elements within the `display: table-cell;`. However, they cause the elements to extend past their container. How can this be fixed?

This problem occurs in IE11 and FireFox 27.0.1. Chrome 33 seems to be fine.

Comment: in menu you have padding-top:10px. Creating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add box-sizing to your .menu

```
.menu{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    box-sizing:border-box; 
}
```

box-sizing allows you to add padding and borders to your elements without it affecting the height. Basically changes the box model

http://jsfiddle.net/LbELK/24/

Comment: I like the idea of border-box, but unfortunately, it still causes problems for cases where I want to add a margin on an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-top on child element instead of using padding-top on parent: http://jsfiddle.net/LbELK/10/

```
.menu{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.menu p {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/neharikapadala/LbELK/13/

```
.menu{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should like try this.. since `<p>` tag have some space by default, so remove margin and padding. also remove the `padding-top` from `.menu` class

```
p{padding:0; margin:0}
```

Here is the working link for you..

http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/LbELK/17/